# SQLAlchemy - initialize roles with user_id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my Playlist model, initialized with a "title" parameter:

```
class Playlist(db.Model):
    """
    Model for storing playlist information belonging to a specific user
    """
    __tablename__ = 'playlist'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def serialize(self):
       return {
           'id' : self.id,
           'created' : self.created,
           'title': self.title,
       }
```

I would like to initialize all my `SQALchemy` roles also passing `user_id`, so as to query my database in this fashion:

```
playlist = Playlist.query.join(User, User.id == Playlist.user_id).filter(
                and_(Playlist.title == 'Cache', User.id == 1)).first()
```

I know that you can query `User` by id like so:

```
User.query.get(1)
```

But what is the best way of *passing* `user_id` at `Playlist` `__init__()`? Is this recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the default constructor that's inherited from `db.Model` is sufficient without needing to supply your own.  The default model constructor will take keyword arguments and assign those values to the correct columns.

I've taken your code from above and adapted it a bit to show this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    name = db.Column(db.String())


class Playlist(db.Model):
    """
    Model for storing playlist information belonging to a specific user
    """
    __tablename__ = 'playlist'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    user = db.relationship("User", backref=db.backref("playlists"))

    def serialize(self):
       return {
          'id' : self.id,
          'created' : self.created,
          'title': self.title,
       }


user = User(name="John")
playlist = Playlist(title="My playlist", user=user)

print(playlist.user)
print(user.playlists)
```

When you pass an instance of User into Playlist, SQLAlchemy will automatically take care of assigning the foreign key to point to that user.

If you still wanted to have a special constructor for Playlist, you'll probably want to add `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` to it, so that the logic in the base constructor is still executed.

Hope that helps!